# JSON.parse() string that contains new line in a value

Tags: javascript

For reasons that can not be changed I have a string with a shitty piece of JSON with new lines like this:

```
{
    "description" : "- some text;
              - some more text;"
}
```

I want to JSON.parse() it so it becomes usable. Of course, it fails when hitting the new line:

`Unexpected token in JSON at position 156`

How can I make this work?

Comment: It doesn't fail because of the semicolon, it fails because of the new-line.

Comment: Your issue is not semicolon. your issue is New line.

Comment: correct. Question remains: how to make it work? ;)

Comment: i have never seen a response like this one a JSON with a new line. :) But anyways tell us about the source of the response.

Comment: The text you posted is neither JSON nor JavaScript code.

Comment: No need to explore the source "For reasons that can not be changed I have a string with a shitty piece of JSON "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove line break,

```
var x = `{
   "description" : "- some text
      - some more text"
      }`
x = x.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" ); 
JSON.parse(x)
```

Comment: If you really want to maintain the line break, instead of the "" in the replace, you can use your special character and the re-add the \n

Answer (score 1):

This is not the semi-colon, but the line-wrap is illegal. Escaped with `\n` this would be valid JSON:

```
{"description": "- some text;\n          - some more text;"}
```

Comment: The line break should be escaped, so: `{"description" : "- some text;\\n          - some more text;"}`

Comment: @Seb Haven't you read the answer?? Unless fixing the syntax, you won't parse that.

Comment: Yes I have. But I can't change the source so how can I escape that programmatically if I only have the given string?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get rid of that new line
2. replace the first and last characters with backticks